# excel vba login to a webpage using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use vba in excel to login with my username and password for a website. for some reason I am getting a user defined error on my top line, can someone show me where I am going wrong. Thanks

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "https://hewdenapps/RDWeb/Pages/en-US/default.aspx"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = False
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "obrianm"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "Perry2012"
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(“input”)
If MyHTML_Element.Type = “submit” Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
 Next
Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

In VBA editor go to *Tools*, *References...* and enable *Microsoft HTML Object Library* and *Microsoft Internet Controls*

Edit:
The list of enabled libraries is saved within the workbook. So any user opening the workbook should have the libraries enabled. Problem could appear when the user have different version of the library (like office 2003 vs office 2010). Than the original library is missing and cannot be loaded. But it is not your case.

This is example how you can dynamically manage the libraries from code. Checking if Outlook library is loaded and activating it from file if it is not (for other libraries get the proper path from the tools, references...).

```
For Each r In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
    If UCase(r.FullPath) = UCase("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSOUTL.OLB")     Then boo_Hit = True
Next
If boo_Hit = False Then ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSOUTL.OLB"
```

Comment: thanks, do you know if this can be enabled using vba? as I want to share this workbook with other users who may not know how to do this